# Extract items from JSON containing a nested array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, sql-server

I have a table like :

| ID | Args |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"**requester**":"Alexandre", "**recipients**":[{"first":"John", "last":"Smith"}, {"first":"Elisa", "last":"Martin"}, {....}, {"first":"Michael", "last":"Dubois"}]} |
| 2 | {"**requester**":"Martin", "**recipients**":[{"first":"Jean", "last":"Dupont"}, {"first":"Elisa", "last":"Martin"}]} |
| ... | ... |
| n | {"**requester**":"Jean", "**recipients**":[{"first":"Jacques", "last":"Dupont"}, {"first":"Elisa", "last":"Gardner"}, {....}, {"first":"Michael", "last":"Dupont"}]} |

What I would like to have:

| ID | Requester | Recipientfirst |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alexandre | John |
| 1 | Alexandre | Elisa |
| 1 | Alexandre | ... |
| 1 | Alexandre | Michael |
| 2 | Martin | Jean |
| ... | ... | ... |

PS: The number of recipients varies.

My tests:

```
select id, JSON_VALUE(args, '$.requester') requester, JSON_VALUE(args, '$.recipients[0].first') recipient
from table
```

But the idea would be to iterate here on the number of recipients (here only 0)

I also achieve to do this :

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max)
select @json = args from table
print @json

SELECT first
FROM OPENJSON( @json, '$.recipients' )
WITH ([first] NVARCHAR(25) '$.first');
```

And it allows to have the firstname list of the first line only.

Does anyone know how to get the desired result?

Comment: Tag the question with the RDBMS you're using. I'm assuming SQL Server given the `NVARCHAR`, but why make anyone assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two levels of `OPENJSON` should do it:

```
SELECT t.id, j1.requester, j2.first_name
FROM t
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(t.args) WITH (   
    requester NVARCHAR(100) '$.requester',  
    recipients NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON  
) AS j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.recipients) WITH (
    first_name NVARCHAR(100) '$.first'
) AS j2
```

Answer (score 2):

My brute force approach would be to use `CROSS APPLY` to open up different parts of the JSON string...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  example
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON(example.json)
         WITH (
           [requester] NVARCHAR(25) '$.requester'
         )
)
  json_requester
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT *
    FROM OPENJSON(example.json, '$.recipients')
         WITH (
           [recipient_first] NVARCHAR(25) '$.first',
           [recipient_last]  NVARCHAR(25) '$.last'
         )
)
  json_recipient
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b79a6ecb271d4322487ede013d54c8e0

Comment: Solid, but seems unnecessarily complicated given that we only need one value from the root object. `SELECT id, JSON_VALUE(json, '$.requester') AS Requester, [first] AS [Recipient first] FROM example CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(json, '$.recipients') WITH ([first] NVARCHAR(25))` should suffice.